# Change font size of List item in Itextsharp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am printing some content in pdf file in a List.

Every thing is working fine but I want to change the font-size of the text displayed using List.

How can I do this?

Here is my code :

```
List lst_rental = new List(List.UNORDERED);
list.IndentationLeft = 30f;
lst_rental.SetListSymbol("\u2022");
lst_rental.Add("Operators");
lst_rental.Add("Insurance");
lst_rental.Add("Lubricants, filters, etc.");
lst_rental.Add("Maintenance services.");
disclaimer.Add(lst_rental);
```

Comment: [Check this, this might be helpful for you](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/81/itextsharp-working-with-fonts)

Comment: @Ullas there is no any example for Lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't creating a `ListItem` yourself in your code. You should create `ListItem` objects. The `ListItem` class is a subclass of `Paragraph` which means you can define the font when you create your `ListItem` objects.

Please go to the [official iText website](http://developers.itextpdf.com/) and use the search box to search for the word "ListItem". You'll find examples such as http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-can-i-generate-pdfua-compatible-pdf-itext

```
List list = new List();
list.Add(new ListItem("item with different font", font);
document.Add(list);
```

In iText 5, you define the font size in the `Font` object. In iText 7, you can define font, font size, and other properties at a higher level (the document level, the list level, etc...), but looking at your code, I see that your using iTextSharp 5 or earlier.

Comment: Kindly help me in this if you can sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37829051/bold-some-text-in-pdf-list