# Bold some text in Pdf List

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I am displaying some content in a List to show it in a pdf file.

Every thing is working fine , but Now I want some text in a List Item Should be Bold.

For Example :

This is **ListItem Bold** Text.

How can I do this ?

Here is my code :

```
 List lst_note = new List(List.ORDERED);

 lst_note.IndentationLeft = 10f;
 lst_note.Add(new iTextSharp.text.ListItem("This single **word** should be Bold", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10)));

 disclaimer.Add(lst_note);
```

**EDIT**

I've tried this :

```
    Font bold  = new Font(FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 10, Font.BOLD));
   lst_terms.Add(new iTextSharp.text.ListItem("Some Text "+ new Chunk("this should bold", bold), FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10)));
```

But this didn't worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the answer of this question: [How can I use regular and bold in a single String?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-can-i-use-regular-and-bold-single-string)

The answer talks about a `Paragraph`, but it also works for a `ListItem` as `ListItem` is a subclass of `Paragraph`:

```
Font regular = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12);
Font bold = Font font = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD);
ListItem li = new ListItem("NAME: ", bold);
li.Add(new Chunk("regular", regular));
```

You can add as many `Chunk` objects using as many different fonts as you want.

Comment: I dont want to take new listitem for every item to be displayed because there are many items to be displayed.I don't think it will be good to take new list item for each and every item

Comment: As @RahulNikate explains that's the only way to do it in iTextSharp 5. You can create a convenience method do to the heavy lifting, but composing list items that require different fonts (font families, font sizes, font styles) is done using different `Chunk`s. Even if you don't create a `ListItem` in your code, iTextSharp creates on internally, so your objection doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I've one more question about this right here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831344/make-listitem-text-bold-but-not-the-list-icon-itextsharp Thanks for your Help sir.

Comment: Kindly help me sir in the question above :(

Comment: I arrived home from a conference in Berlin at 1 AM this morning. I had 4 hours of sleep and now I'm at the airport waiting for a plane to Milan. Kindly understand that I have my job and you have yours. I'm not going to do my job *and your job*. Putting pressure on me is not the way to go. It feels like you're trying to abuse me. **Not appreciated!**

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using `Paragraph` and `Chunks` like below:

```
Chunk c1 = new Chunk("This single", new Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            Chunk c2 = new Chunk("word", new Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            Chunk c3 = new Chunk("should be Bold", new Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));

            Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph();
            p2.Add(c1);
            p2.Add(c2);
            p2.Add(c3);

 List lst_note = new List(List.ORDERED);

 lst_note.IndentationLeft = 10f;
 lst_note.Add(new iTextSharp.text.ListItem(p2);

 disclaimer.Add(lst_note);
```

Comment: there are many list items to be displayed.I don't think that this is prefered to many of the chunks and paragraphs for each and every list item.Is there any other way

Comment: You can create one function to create paragraph and add chunks in it and call that function while adding `ListItem`. I don't see any other way of doing it. However you can try wrapping the text in `<b>word to bold</b>. Not sure it will work.

Comment: *there are many list items to be displayed.I don't think that this is prefered to many of the chunks and paragraphs for each and every list item.Is there any other way* - This actually is how the data is always represented under the hood whether one uses simplified convenience methods or the more complicated and more versatile ones.

Comment: Haha I also realized it. Blunder Typo. Anyway.... Its nice to see @Bruno Lowagie here, Original Developer iText library. :D