# Make ListItem Text Bold but not the List Icon itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am displaying a list using itextsharp in a pdf file .

Some of the Contents in a List item are being Bold as I asked it in my Question :

[Bold some text in Pdf List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37829051/bold-some-text-in-pdf-list/37829261?noredirect=1#comment63121247_37829261)

Now the problem is if I bold some text of Listitem , the List number is also getting Bold.

For Example :

**1.Bold Text**

it should be

1. **Bold Text**

Here is the Snapshot :

[image]

How can I resolve this ?

Here is my Code :

```
 c1 = new Chunk("Earth Pit.", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 10,iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE));
        c2 = new Chunk(" The existing earth...", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10));
        p_chunk = new Paragraph();
        p_chunk.Add(c1);
        p_chunk.Add(c2);
        lst_terms.Add(new iTextSharp.text.ListItem(p_chunk));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Chunk c1 = new Chunk("Earth Pit.", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 10,iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE));
Chunk c2 = new Chunk(" The existing earth...", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10));
ListItem li = new ListItem("", FontFactory.GetFont(TIMES_ROMAN, 10));
p.Add(c1);
p.Add(c2);
lst_terms.Add(li);
```

Why are you creating a `Paragraph` object when you actually need a `ListItem`?